# How to correct typos?

Tags: support, editing

When I try to correct a typo, I get the following error:

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

Are typos not worth it to correct?

Comment: when you unlock the "edit everywhere" privilege, to my recollection this limitation goes away. As it is, every edit of yours is vetted by two additional users, and this restriction is for their benefit (making each edit count)

Comment: This isn't CR specific. Whilst it's meant to improve quality of edits, it makes people just not edit. Unless you know what a HTML comment looks like, and it just becomes a bad joke.

Comment: This is not a bug, but [meta-tag:status-bydesign] as indicated by the comments above.

Comment: Just to confirm what Vogel612 said, I did not get warned about the 6 char limit when I fixed a small issue in this post.

Answer (score 4):

> Are typos not worth it to correct?

Absolutely, but not at any and all cost.

When you suggest an edit, the edit will be placed in the review queue. Now, either the author of the post or two reviewers will have to agree with the edit to have it succeed (or one of the editors forces the edit by further editing it). This is to ensure the quality of the edits and prevent nefarious ones. It's a complicated method of rate-limiting that's not perfect but works relatively well.

So your edits create work for others. Not a problem, but it's good to have limitations on what kind of edits can be made to prevent a flood of minor edits. Minor typographic mistakes can also be pointed out in the comments. So if that's all there is to fix, point it out there. But is that really all there is to fix? Aren't there other improvements to be made? On longer questions, there often are. And if not, let the veterans handle it.

Above 2000 rep you can instantly edit posts without your edits having to go through the queue. At this point, the minimum character limit is dropped. The system trusts you. This is the point where you can fix those minor mistakes without problems. At this point, the system expects you to understand the site good enough not to cause too many problems.

It's also all explained [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251618/1014587). Same rules apply.